# Deleting Comments on A Post Deletes The Entire Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to delete a comment on a post, I end up deleting the entire post instead.

Comments Controllers

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find_by(id: params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = 
   @micropost.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name,:body))
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment Posted"
  end
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

   redirect_to request.referrer
  end
end
```

Comments View

```
<li>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <% @post.comments.each do |comments| %>
      <li>
        <article class="article-container-full">
          <%=  comments.name%>
          <hr>
         <%= comments.body %>
          <hr>
          <p class="posted-time"> Posted <%= 
           time_ago_in_words(comments.created_at) %> ago</p>
          <p>
          <%= link_to 'Delete', @comment, :method => :delete, data: 
            {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}%>
         </p>
       </article>
       <br>
      </li>
    </ol>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Comments Routes

```
 micropost_comments GET    
 /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          
 comments#index
                    POST   
 /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          
 comments#create
 new_micropost_comment GET    
 /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
 edit_micropost_comment GET    
 /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) 
  comments#edit
  micropost_comment GET    
  /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      
  comments#show
                    PATCH  
  /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      
  comments#update
                    PUT    
  /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      
  comments#update
                    DELETE 
  /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      
  comments#destroy
```

Micropost Model:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :headline, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 10000 }

end
```

Comments Model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :micropost
end
```

Destroy method from Microposts Controller just incase:

```
  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Post deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || current_user
  end
```

I have a feeling i am missing something very small but I just can see it. Instead of just deleting the comment, its deletes the entire post along with everything else associated to it.

Comment: Can you post code contents of post and comment association?

Comment: Double check how you defined `dependent: :destroy` in your models, you can read more about it here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark

Comment: @Gabbar I have added the models now  for you to see. I assume thats what you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this-

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', micropost_comment_path(@post, comments), :method => :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}%>
```

Or-

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', [@post, comments], :method => :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}%>
```

Comment: @gabber First one gives me the following error when trying to load the page `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil, :micropost_id=>"37"}, missing required keys: [:id]`  Second one deletes the entire post along with the comment.

Comment: @JackGruber I didn't see as it's `comments` not `@comment` please have a look at updated answer.

Comment: Both of these work perfectly, many thanks. It allows me to delete the comment regardless of who I am logged in as, but thats logic I suppose I will have to work out for myself to only display the delete button to the comment poster.

Comment: @JackGruber Glad to know that, one thing I would like to add up iterating over comments should mean to take one comment one by one so instead of `comments` parameter you should use the singular version which is `comment`. Meanwhile, let me know if you need any further guidance. Thanks.

Comment: @JackGruber  Also you should avoid fat arrow old syntax (`:method => :delete`), other than this if you don't need user-friendly routes than you can use `shallow`

Comment: How curious to take the elements of other people's answers and add them to your answer as new comments - without referencing the other people's answers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you haven't initialized `@comment` anywhere. That's why you are getting this error.

Another thing is you shouldn't use the `comments` variable in do..end loop. As it, iterates over comments make it singular.

Try following,

```
<li>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <li>
        <article class="article-container-full">
          <%=  comment.name%>
          <hr>
         <%= comment.body %>
          <hr>
          <p class="posted-time"> Posted <%= 
           time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</p>
          <p>
          <%= link_to "Delete Comment", [@post ,comment], :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete%>
         </p>
       </article>
       <br>
      </li>
    </ol>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: This also work perfectly, many thanks. It allows me to delete the comment regardless of who I am logged in as, but thats logic I suppose I will have to work out for myself to only display the delete button to the comment poster.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you already have an answer, but you might also take a look at [shallow nesting](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting). Something, perhaps, like:

```
resources :posts do 
  resources :comments, shallow: :true
end
```

Which will give you the following `comments` routes:

```
    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)        comments#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)        comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)    comments#new
     edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)              comments#edit
          comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#show
                  PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#update
                  PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#update
                  DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#destroy
```

Now (as you can see), the `DELETE` action no longer requires `post_id`. So you can do (borrowing from Krupa Suthar in the other answer):

```
<%= link_to "Delete", comment, confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete %>
```

In which case your original code:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @comment, :method => :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

... was actually quite close except you needed `comment` instead of `@comment`.

In this particular case, shallow nesting (along with using the more modern `method: :delete` instead of `:method => :delete`) saves you around 11-22 characters:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', [@post, comments], :method => :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
<%= link_to "Delete", [@post ,comment], :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', @comment, :method => :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
<%= link_to "Delete", comment, confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete %>
```

Which represents a ~14-22% reduction in your code. It may not seem like much, but over your lifetime of programming, those characters add up.

Comment: Very nice. Very nice indeed. Thank you suggestions, I shall look into implementing them.